# MyAnimelist OAuth2 Implementaion in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement OAuth2 for the my animelist api in siwftUI but i dont know what wrong .This is my first time using OAuth 2.

```
import SwiftUI
import OAuthSwift
import CryptoKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isAuthorized = false
    @State private var accessToken: String?
    @State private var refreshToken: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if isAuthorized {
                Text("Access Token: \(accessToken ?? "N/A")")
                Text("Refresh Token: \(refreshToken ?? "N/A")")
            } else {
                Button("Authorize") {
                    authorize()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func authorize() {
        print("Starting authorization process...")
        
        let oauthSwift = OAuth2Swift(
            consumerKey: "e333019e486e544405bfbaac0f95cc13",
            consumerSecret: "",
            authorizeUrl: "https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/authorize",
            responseType: "code"
        )
        
        let codeVerifier = generateCodeVerifier()
        let codeChallenge = generateCodeChallenge(from: codeVerifier)
        let state = "R7SBW5"
        
        print("Code Verifier: \(codeVerifier)")
        print("Code Challenge: \(codeChallenge)")
        print("Random State: \(state)")
        
        oauthSwift.authorize(
            withCallbackURL: URL(string: "https://LuffyTv.com") ?? "",
            scope: "scope",
            state: state,
            codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
            codeChallengeMethod: "S256",
            codeVerifier: codeVerifier
        ) { result in
            print(result)
            switch result {
            case .success(let (credential, _, _)):
                self.accessToken = credential.oauthToken
                self.refreshToken = credential.oauthRefreshToken
                self.isAuthorized = true
                print("Authorization successful!")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Authorization failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func generateRandomState() -> String {
        let randomState = UUID().uuidString
        print("Generated random state: \(randomState)")
        return randomState
    }

    private func generateCodeVerifier() -> String {
        let length = 43
        let charset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~"
        return (0..<length).map { _ in charset.randomElement()! }.map(String.init).joined()
    }

    private func generateCodeChallenge(from verifier: String) -> String {
        let verifierData = verifier.data(using: .utf8)!
        let hashedVerifier = SHA256.hash(data: verifierData)
        return Data(hashedVerifier).base64EncodedString()
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "-")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "_")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "=", with: "")
    }
}
```

It is going to browser and i click on. allow then nothing happens. I am in confusion what i should give for the callback Url in the code as well as MyAnimeList.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7f82b.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3amjK.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjjWl.png)